# command problem

Tags: 14.04

When I tried to see the contents in a directory in cae computer it is showing this problem

```
ryeasmin42@ch208t:~$ ls -alt
could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It sounds you have destroyed your PATH variable. What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

This very first error message shows that the search for a **ls** command is first attempted using the packaging system. **sources.list** is missing.

> Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
>
> The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
>
> ls: command not found

PATH environment variable is a list of directories used by the shell to look for commands. Directories in this list are separated with **:**

The **ls** command is not found because your PATH environment variable is not defined or does not contain **/bin**.

try this:

```
/bin/ls -alt
```

The best would be to add **/bin** in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: great! if the answer helped you, please mark it as  the formal answer.